# Integral with $\cos$ function

Tags: residue-calculus

I know how to compute $\displaystyle\int_{0}^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x^2+1)}dx$. In fact, we can compute $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x^2+1)}dx$ and just use the fact that $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x(x^2+1)}$ is an even function. Now, I have this question and I do not know how to solve it.

Compute $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos x}{x(x^2+1)}dx.$$ Here, we can compute $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\cos x}{x(x^2+1)}dx$, which is $0$, but I do not know how to reduce it to $\displaystyle\int_{0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos x}{x(x^2+1)}dx$. In fact, the function $g(x)=\dfrac{\cos x}{x(x^2+1)}dx$ is odd. Can you give me some hint?

Comment: Um, the integral doesn't converge. Bad singularity at $x=0$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 How to show that it does not converge?

Comment: @Cachorro: For $0 < x < 1$, $\frac{\cos x}{x(x^2+1)} > \frac{\cos x}{2x} > \frac{1/2}{2x} = \frac{1}{4x}$, and that behaves badly enough in that interval for the integral to fail to converge.

Comment: So, my professor made a mistake in saying "Compute $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\cos x}{x(x^2+1)}dx$ using complex method" ?

Comment: @Cachorro Trick question. Some profs are like that. Or maybe a genuine mistake on his or her part.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.